# Deleting the font object

Tags: c++, winapi

After creating a simple Win32 application in C/C++ I send a message to a control in order to apply some nice fonts using the following API:

```
SendMessage(hwndEdit, WM_SETFONT, WPARAM(hFont), TRUE);
```

Is it necessary to delete this font object afterwards or not? The deletion is performed in the WM_DESTROY message.

```
case WM_DESTROY:
        DeleteObject(hFont); // Delete font object
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
```

Comment: Resource leak is similar to a regular memory leak. If you have one window which is created only once, and it creates the font only once, then there is no issue because OS will clean things up at the end. In real world application your window could be created and destroyed many times in the same process, or font is created many times inside a paint function, so you should delete the fonts manually when they are no longer needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the [WM_SETFONT message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632642(v=vs.85).aspx) seems to be pretty clear on this :

> The application should call the `DeleteObject` function to delete the
>   font when it is no longer needed; for example, after it destroys the
>   control.

So, yes, you should call `DeleteObject` in the `WM_DESTROY` handler of the object that created the control.

Comment: That "should" part is what got me confused for the first time.

Comment: @RawN Be careful not to destroy it while `hwndEdit` is still using it. See [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080912-00/?p=20893) for more info.

Comment: @andlabs: Please explain your comment. If I use edit control in dialog, after calling WM_DESTROY is also destroying edit control, so NO EDIT control use it,

Comment: @user2120666 Almost. [You get `WM_DESTROY` before your children do.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050726-00/?p=34803) That being said, yes, in general what you said is safe. But the OP did not say whether `hwndEdit` is a child of their window, so I am pointing this out to make the answer more clear.